# Probability - tennis players and random variables

Tags: probability, random-variables

There are two tennis players playing against each other. Denote the players player1 and player2. The probability of player1 to win a single match is $\mathbb{P} = \dfrac{2}{3}$, independently of the results of the previous matches. The two play until one of them wins 3 matches. What is the probability that player1 wins the game?

So I started by Defining a random variable $X_{i}$ that indicates whether player1 win or lose in the i'ts match. Meaning, $X_{i} = 1$ if player1 wins ths i'th match, and $X_{i} = 0$ otherwise. Let's denote by $A_{n}$ the event in which after $n$ matches player1 wins, and later we will take $n \rightarrow \infty$.
Now we can notice that for every $1 \leq i \leq n$ it holds that $X_{i} \sim Ber \left( \dfrac{2}{3} \right)$, and so $Y = \sum ^{n}_{i=1}X_{i} \sim Bin \left( n, \dfrac{2}{3} \right)$, and that's because all the $X_{i}$'s are independent on each other.
Now we want to calculate the event $\mathbb{P} \left( A_{n} \right) = \mathbb{P} \left( Y=3 \right) = \begin{pmatrix} n \\ 3 \end{pmatrix}\cdot \begin{pmatrix} 2 \\ 3 \end{pmatrix}^{3}\cdot \left( \dfrac{1}{3}\right) ^{n-3}$ and after simplifying it we get $\mathbb{P} \left( A_{n} \right) =\mathbb{P} \left( Y=3 \right) = \dfrac{4 \cdot n \cdot \left( n-1 \right) \cdot \left( n-2 \right)}{3^{n+1}}$, So $\lim _{n\rightarrow \infty } \mathbb{P} \left( A_{n}\right) = 0$.
So the probability is $0$ ? It doesn't make any sense for me.
I would glad for some help.

Comment: Maybe you are overcomplicating things. You could consider the case of player 1 not winning a game, given by the probability $1-p=1/3$. Not winning in three games is then $(1-p)^{3}$ and hence winning three games is  $1-(1-p)^{3}\approx 0.96$.

Comment: Is your question Player A is first to win $3$ matches, or does Player A have to become *ahead* of B by $3$ matches.

Comment: @trueblueanil Player A is first to win 3 matches

Comment: **To the OP**: Sorry for the confusion.  I have deleted my answer.  I was misinterpreting your posting.

Comment: @user1114191: Your formulation reflects player 1 (or A) winning *at least* 1 match

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No player wins in less than $3$ matches, and there will always be a winner in no more than $5$ matches. Hence, if you want to know the probability that player$1$ wins $3$ matches in a given game, then you must sum the following probabilities:

(1) that player$1$ wins $2$ of the first $2$ matches and then wins the $3$rd match

(2) that player$1$ wins $2$ of the first $3$ matches and then wins the $4$th match

(3) that player$1$ wins $2$ of the first $4$ matches and then wins the $5$th match

We compute this as follows...

$$ {2 \choose 2} \Big( \frac{2}{3} \Big)^3 \Big( 1-\frac{2}{3} \Big)^{3-3} + 
{3 \choose 2} \Big( \frac{2}{3} \Big)^3 \Big( 1-\frac{2}{3} \Big)^{4-3} + 
{4 \choose 2} \Big( \frac{2}{3} \Big)^3 \Big( 1-\frac{2}{3} \Big)^{5-3} $$

$$ = {2 \choose 2} \Big( \frac{2}{3} \Big)^3 \Big( \frac{1}{3} \Big)^{3-3} + 
{3 \choose 2} \Big( \frac{2}{3} \Big)^3 \Big( \frac{1}{3} \Big)^{4-3} + 
{4 \choose 2} \Big( \frac{2}{3} \Big)^3 \Big( \frac{1}{3} \Big)^{5-3} $$

$$ = \Big( \frac{2}{3} \Big)^3 + 
{3 \choose 2} \Big( \frac{2}{3} \Big)^3 \frac{1}{3} + 
{4 \choose 2} \Big( \frac{2}{3} \Big)^3 \Big( \frac{1}{3} \Big)^{2} $$

$$ = \frac{8}{27} + 
3 \Big( \frac{8}{27} \Big) \frac{1}{3} + 
6 \Big( \frac{8}{27} \Big) \frac{1}{9} \approx 0.7901$$

Comment: Yes after a different computation that's also what I got, thanks a lot!

Comment: glad to help!!!

Answer (score 3):

Just for alternative. This is equivalent to the following problem; if each of $5$ ordered balls can be red, blue, or green with equal probability, what is the probability that there are less than 3 red balls ?

$$
\frac{\binom{5}{3}2^{3}+\binom{5}{4}2^{4}+\binom{5}{5}2^{5}}{3^{5}}=\frac{64}{81}
$$

The same result as the accepted answer.

Comment: You are computing winning a 5 set tennis match, while OP is asking for winning 3 **matches** in his question.

Comment: @trueblueanil they are the same, as far as probability is concerned. Even after one player win (by winning 3 matches), they can still play until they play a total of 5 games without changing the outcome of the match.

Comment: @trueblueanil I mean they can play a total of 5 matches without changing the outcome of the game

Comment: @trueblueanil that is true, but after winning 3-0 they can play two additional matches without changing who wins. The same with 3-1, can play one additional matches.

Comment: I see, he is wanting first to 3 = best of $5\quad$ +1